# AJAX Hotlinking/back/refresh capability using .load

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser

Below is my AJAX code loading a DIV from an external HTML file into a target DIV onto another HTML page, can anyone suggest how to make the page with the content loaded have back/refresh/hotlinking capabilities keeping the DIV loaded in the page?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#about2', function() {
        $("#content").load("content.html #about", function() {
        $.getScript("slides.js", function() {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        });
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#process2', function() {
        $("#content").load("content.html #process", function() {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#materials2', function() {
        $("#content").load("content.html #materials", function() {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        });
    });   

    $(document).on('click', '#radio2', function() {
        $("#content2").load("content.html #radiofriendly", function() {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        });
    });
    });
```

Basically, i'd like:

http://crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html#process

To link straight to the page with the #process DIV loaded, allowing for refresh, back, forward browser functions. Any suggestions? At the minute it just links to http://crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html with the original DIV loaded.

Thanks in advance, having real trouble with JQuery.

EDIT****

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '#about2',function ParseURL() {
    switch(location.hash.split("&")[0]) {
        case '#about':
            $("#content").load("content.html #about", function() {
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;

$(document).on('click', '#process2',function ParseURL() {
    switch(location.hash.split("&")[0]) {
        case '#process':
            $("#content").load("content.html #process", function() {
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;

$(document).on('click', '#materials2',function ParseURL() {
    switch(location.hash.split("&")[0]) {
        case '#process':
            $("#content").load("content.html #materials", function() {
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;

$(document).on('click', '#pricing2',function ParseURL() {
    switch(location.hash.split("&")[0]) {
        case '#process':
            $("#content").load("content.html #pricing", function() {
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;

         default:
    }
}

$(window).bind("pageshow", function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
        ParseURL();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function ($) {
    ParseURL();
});
```

Comment: This is how it works, when you load content dynamically on events, that content is gone when you navigate away from the site. There are ways to keep persistent storage, but to keep track of all the dynamic changes you're making, and make them reappear on page reload is going to be a rather daunting task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hashchange event to detect the URL modification. This will allow you to update the DIV after your loads. When you use back and forward, there will be an event. Use that to look at the hash, and load the content DIV appropriately.

Here's a great jQuery plugin that supports the functionality you want with examples: [Ben Alman Hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)

As it currently is, you page is updating correctly when you select a link from the left column but NOT updating when using history.

ADD THESE TO the javascript associated with print.html NOT in content.html!!!  I believe you call it core.js?

```
//You will need one entry in this switch statement for *each* hash value: #process, #materials, #pricing, etc
function ParseURL() {
    switch(location.hash.split("&")[0]) {
        case '#materials':
            $("#content").load("content.html #materials", function() {
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;
        case '#process':
            $("#content").load("content.html #process", function() {
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;
         default:
    }
}

//This should update on history button use
$(window).bind("pageshow", function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
        ParseURL();
    }
});

//Using ParseURL inside your ready function will allow linking directly to a sub page
//This allows those going to the URL:
// http://crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html#pricing directly will should display the 
// pricing information in the content DIV.
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    ParseURL();
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, any tips on how to use it in the above code successfully? I have attempted to use this plugin before, but i can't remember it being successful.

Comment: The code in this answer doesn't require the plugin. It should work on your page as is.

Comment: Also, the bbq plugin may NOT be what you want. It's a heavier version that the more minimalist jQuery hashchange plugin.

Comment: See my answer below utilising the code typed above, it doesn't work however if someone can see how it is going wrong. If you go on the page, it doesnt work, it needs a plugin to utilise it, i've always known that much, just failed to utilise it. I'll look into the Onhashexchange plugin, i have also dabbled with that unsuccessfully.

Comment: I saw that you used the BBQ plugin. The more up to date plugin is: http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/raw/v1.3/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js

Comment: I did indeed use it, but not the stripped down version, the whole version is currently linked to my site and head section.

Comment: https://github.com/balupton/History.js/

Is another one i have tried to use unsuccessfully.

Comment: I'm looking at the page. It updates the #content div when you click the links and changes the hash part of the URL. All you need now is to handle the pageshow event when you use the back-forward buttons, and load based on the URL.

Comment: I'm currently struggling to implement a pageshow event, what you can see is as far as i got with it before everything i tried failed to work, i'll have a look through some Ben Alman examples copy code bits.

Comment: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/document_domain/

This is the best example i can find, and it seems to be rooted in php, which i have 0 experience with, anyone able to help me simply add a pageshow event to the above AJAX code?

Comment: See my edits. The code above should be added to the print.html, not content.html.

Comment: If you look at my original post,i have edited it to integrate the code you just wrote, it doesn't seem to work, i've added it for 4 AJAX .load links, i'm not too sure if i've integrated it correctly with the .on(click function, any suggestions? Thankyou btw.

Comment: Scrap that, your code works for hotlinking and refresh-ability but the back button doesnt work with it, i'll look further into this.